# How to use Hibernate Annotations to add an index on a Lob / Clob / tinyblob

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a bean which I map to the database using Hibernate. I'm using Hibernate Annotations to indicate the mapping I want, and to create the indices. The thoroughly simplified code is shown below.

The problem I have is that the indices on my byte[] field are not created; specifically that my multi-field index sysUuid does not get created (see example code). In the Hibernate debug logs I do not even see an attempt to create an index!

I'd like to point out that an @Index annotation on the uuid field also does not result in an index on the database.

I do know how to create an index by hand using MySQL:

```
create index sysuuid on persons ( system, `uuid`(8) );
```

where the interesting features are that uuid needs to be escaped (as it is a MySQL function) and that a length needs to be given on the field (as with text fields).

I however have not found a way to give the index length field using Hibernate Annotations so I cannot test wether that is the problem. It is however certain that naming the field "uuid(8)" in the annotation does not work.

```
@Entity
// The UniqueConstraints work 
@Table(name = "persons", 
   uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"uid", "system"}) } )
// but these don't generate an index
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo="persons", 
   indexes={@Index(name="sysUuid",  columnNames={"system", "uuid"})  } )
public class Person  {
    @Basic 
    @NotNull
    private String uid;

    @Basic
    private int system;

    // Gets mapped to tinyblob
    @Basic
    @Size(min = 16, max = 16)
    private byte[] uuid;

    // getters and setters here 
}
```

What I'd like to ask you is: Is it possible to add an index on a lob using an annotation, and if so, how?

**EDIT**

It is indeed possible for me to move to a String-based UUID, but I'm not really comfortable with that as uuid is conceptually a 16-byte identifier.

I strongly prefer the Java types to match the problem domain.

And as I said - I do have an SQL statement handy so I can deploy the code + a SQL script. I just think it's better do have self-documenting code whenever feasible.

**EDIT & Added Bounty**

I believe the index I need cannot be created using Hibernate Annotations (re. Matt Solnit's answer).

I however would appreciate a bit more information about creating indices with Hibernate Annotations in general so the eventual answer ends up documenting the limitations of the 
API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using Hibernate's [auxiliary objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping-database-object.html) support, but it cannot be done using annotations :-(.

In your example, it would look something like this (lots of stuff omitted for brevity):

```
<class name="Person" table="persons">
  <!-- whatever -->
  <database-object>
    <create>create index sysuuid on persons ( system, `uuid`(8) )</create>
    <drop>drop index sysuuid</drop>
    <dialect-scope name="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
  </database-object>
</class>
```

I apologize for the lack of an annotation-based answer :-(.  Hopefully this helps.

**NOTE**:  If you do take this approach, be aware that the dialect scope has to match *exactly*.  For example, if your Hibernate configuration says to use `MySQL5InnoDBDialect`, then you must have this dialect in the `<dialect-scope>` element as well.  Using `MySQLDialect` will not work even though it is the super-class of the InnoDB dialect.

Comment: Thank you. I will not use this approach but stick with my SQL script. If I had some Hibernate experts as a collegue I might have gone with this solution. But I fear (due to your note) that in the future, when switching dialects, problems might arise :) And an SQL script is, for my company, a more intuitive solution.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to specify index length on a _primary key_?

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to do is to define your UUID property as a String rather than a byte array.  That way Hibernate will map it to a character column in the database rather than a LOB, and I think it'll create the index you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  But a byte[] is what I have. I'm not all that happy with modifying my problem domain on the capabilities of one my tools. My successor won't understand why my UUID, which comes as a byte[] from an external source, is suddenly a String. 

Apart from that - which charset should the String be ? :-)

For now I just deliver an index creating SQL script with my app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my research results with MySQL. If you have a field which length is big:

```
@Column(length = 2000)
public String getMessageId() {
    return messageId;
}
```

then its type would be BLOB and indexing would not work:

```
HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create index messageid_idx on MessageDetails (messageId)
BLOB/TEXT column 'messageId' used in key specification without a key length
```

If you use annotations, the only way to add custom sql is the following:

```
    cfg.addAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new SimpleAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(
            "CREATE INDEX messageId_IDX ON MessageDetails(MessageID(128))",
            "DROP INDEX messageId_IDX ON MessageDetails"));
```

where cfg is object that is used for registering annotations:

```
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(MessageDetails.class);
```

this works for me. Thanx for your attention.