# How to annotate a PostgreSQL GIN index in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

How do I properly annotate a PostgreSQL GIN index with Hibernate?

```
@Index(...)
String text;
```

Does hibernate create a GIN index by default, or do I have to set a special property somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can't create custom indexes directly with Hibernate's annotations. See related: [How to use Hibernate Annotations to add an index on a Lob / Clob / tinyblob](https://stackoverflow.com/q/858336/398670), where an answer mentions how to do it with auxillary objects.

In your situation I would query the system catalogs ([`information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) or [`pg_catalog`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html)) for the index at startup and, if it wasn't found, execute `CREATE INDEX` statement with native SQL.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12601305/398670) to a very similar question about creating triggers in Hibernate.