# Specifying index method when using @Index annotation

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, postgis, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-spatial

I'm using (spatial) hibernate annotations to create a schema for a spatial application that  is implemented on top of PostGIS. When creating the database schema from my annotated classes, I'm in need to create spatial indexes for speeding up spatial queries that are used throughout the application.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_CLASS")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(
    appliesTo = "MY_CLASS", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "idx_my_class_sidx",
            columnNames = { "GEOM" }) })
public class MyClass {
    [...]
    @Column(name = "GEOM")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    private LineString geom;
    [...]
}
```

While the exported schema contains the index, unfortunately it has been created with an undesired index method; hibernate seems to default to `btree` however PostGIS recommends the use of `GIST` indexes when dealing with spatial data (see http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#id441511).

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_my_class_sidx
    ON my_class
    USING btree
    (geom);
```

Whereas I might just fall back creating the index with plain SQL, I'm wondering if there is a way to use hibernate annotations to override the default method type for PostgreSQL? Solutions or even ideas how to do that would be highly appreciated.

TIA,
Tilman

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to annotate a PostgreSQL GIN index in Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243263/how-to-annotate-a-postgresql-gin-index-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated the issue and it seems like Denis is right. From looking at the class `Index` from the current hibernate implementation (cf. [1](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/mapping/Index.java%5d)), it becomes clear that specification of index types is not supported, yet.

```java
public static String buildSqlCreateIndexString(
        Dialect dialect,
        String name,
        Table table,
        Iterator<Column> columns,
        java.util.Map<Column, String> columnOrderMap,
        boolean unique,
        String defaultCatalog,
        String defaultSchema
) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder( "create" )
            .append( unique ?
                    " unique" :
                    "" )
            .append( " index " )
            .append( dialect.qualifyIndexName() ?
                    name :
                    StringHelper.unqualify( name ) )
            .append( " on " )
            .append( table.getQualifiedName( dialect, defaultCatalog, defaultSchema ) )
            .append( " (" );
    while ( columns.hasNext() ) {
        Column column = columns.next();
        buf.append( column.getQuotedName( dialect ) );
        if ( columnOrderMap.containsKey( column ) ) {
            buf.append( " " ).append( columnOrderMap.get( column ) );
        }
        if ( columns.hasNext() ) buf.append( ", " );
    }
    buf.append( ")" );
    return buf.toString();
}
```

The most simple workaround is to call `session.createSQLQuery()` and to issue `CREATE INDEX` yourself. This however, is a database-specific operation that needs to be maintained by the applications developer (in case the database is changed).