# Set index length of TEXT

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I want to add an index on a text field via xml mapping. Like suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/860955/3256688 I'm trying to use auxiliary database objects, because an index length is not supported in the mapping itself. But for me it looks like Hibernate ignores this part of the mapping completely.

Here's my code. Want to add an index `url_idx` to the table `MY_TABLE`.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    ...
    <mapping resource="mytable.hbm.xml"/>
    ...
```

mytable.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.company.MyTable" table="MY_TABLE">
        ...
        <property name="url" column="url" type="text"/>
        ...
    </class>
    <database-object>
        <create>CREATE INDEX url_idx ON MY_TABLE (`url`(30))</create>
        <drop>DROP INDEX ON MY_TABLE `url_idx`</drop>
        <dialect-scope name="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"></dialect-scope>
    </database-object>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In the logging of hibernate (debug-level) I see that every table and index is created correctly, but I find nothing about `url_idx`. And of course, there is no index created in the database.

Any clue what I'm missing here?

**Edit:** Very interesting: if I do the schema export with the tool `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport` it works as it should work. But still the same if I initialize Hibernate in my code.

Btw. I'm using Hibernate 4.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` has to be `create` or `create-drop`, otherwise it the code will not be executed. I think that's a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem, You create with

```
 <create>CREATE INDEX url_idx ON MY_TABLE (`url`(30))</create>
```

And you delete it with

```
<drop>DROP INDEX ON MY_TABLE `url_idx`</drop>
```

Comment: What do you mean? I do not understand... it's exactly the same way like I posted it, or?

Comment: Remove drop instruction you'll see your index in database